# Jenkins pipeline: how to upload artifacts with s3 plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

Im trying to upload artifacts to an s3 bucket after a successful build, but i cant find any working example to be implemented into a stage/node block.

any idea ( s3 plugin installed, jenkins v2.32 )?

```
node {
  sh 'echo ""> 1.jar'
  archiveArtifacts artifacts: '1.jar', fingerprint: true
  // upload to s3 bucket ???
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Detailed steps:

1. Install Pipeline AWS Plugin.
   Go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Available tab -> Filter by 'Pipeline AWS'.
   Install the plugin.
2. Add Credentials as per your environment. Example here:

   Jenkins > Credentials > System > Global credentials (unrestricted) -> Add

   Kind = AWS Credentials
   and add your AWS credentials

   Note the ID
3. Then in your Pipeline project (Similar to the code I use)

   ```
   node {

       stage('Upload') {

           dir('path/to/your/project/workspace'){

               pwd(); //Log current directory

               withAWS(region:'yourS3Region',credentials:'yourIDfromStep2') {

                    def identity=awsIdentity();//Log AWS credentials

                   // Upload files from working directory 'dist' in your project workspace
                   s3Upload(bucket:"yourBucketName", workingDir:'dist', includePathPattern:'**/*');
               }

           };
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 11):

Looking at the [Pipeline Steps documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-aws/) on the Jenkins website, it shows that the [Pipeline AWS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+AWS+Plugin) provides an `s3Upload` step.

Comment: Can you give us an example of how to use it to upload a local file in the current directory to the root of a bucket?

Comment: @esmiralha were you able to use s3Upload to upload a local file to the root of the bucket??

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
s3Upload(file:'file.txt', bucket:'my-bucket', path:'path/to/target/file.txt')
```

I think it is easier to show the direct plugin documentation URL.
You can find the plugin documentation [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin).

As you are looking for a way to upload files to S3, [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-aws-plugin#s3upload) are some examples.