# Groovy compilation errors with S3Publisher plugin in Jenkinsfile Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

A very novice Jenkins question but I have unable to find any solutions and probably due to my limited understanding of Jenkins, maybe not able to make sense of the documentation available. I am working with the S3publisher plugin in Jenkins and have correctly configured the aws credentials for this plugin. However, I am unable to write a Jenkinsfile to upload a file using this plugin. I am pasting a truncated pipeline below:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage("publish to s3") {
            steps {
                    //$class: 'S3BucketPublisher',
                    $class: 'S3Upload',
                    profileName: ‘myawsprofile’,
                    entries: [[
                        bucket: ‘mybucket’, 
                        excludedFile: '', 
                        flatten: false, 
                        gzipFiles: false, 
                        keepForever: false, 
                        managedArtifacts: false, 
                        noUploadOnFailure: false, 
                        selectedRegion: 'us-iso-east-1',
                        howDirectlyInBrowser: false, 
                        sourceFile: ‘myfile’, 
                        storageClass: 'STANDARD', 
                        uploadFromSlave: false, 
                        useServerSideEncryption: false]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

I have done various modifications and I keep running into `org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed` error while running the Jenkins pipeline. The latest error that I see is:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 27: unexpected token: S3Upload @ line 27, column 29.
                       $class: 'S3Upload',
```

Has anyone run into this before or let me know where shall I look to get some more understanding of how this plugin is supposed to work thru Jenkinsfile?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this plugin specifically, but looking at the documentation, you can try something like this:

```
S3Upload {
    profileName: ‘myawsprofile’,
    ....
```

If that doesn't work, you can possibly look to using the [Pipeline AWS](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/) plugin, which is much more popular and has better support/documentation. It also has the ability to do more than just deal with S3, and is simple to use. For your particular case, the related documentation can be found [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/#plugin-content-s3upload). Additionally, you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52306489/3730626) helpful, since it talks about uploading to S3 end-to-end with the Pipeline AWS plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your input as the pipeline AWS plugin does seem like have much more functionality. However, I was able to get the S3 Publisher plugin to work. Will post the code snippet in case anyone else runs into the same.

Answer (score 0):

Used the Pipeline syntax to get the code snippet which I posted into a stage as a step as follows:

```
stage("publish to s3") {
           steps {
                s3Upload consoleLogLevel: 'INFO', dontSetBuildResultOnFailure: false, dontWaitForConcurrentBuildCompletion: false, entries: [[bucket: 'my-S3-bucket', excludedFile: '', flatten: false, gzipFiles: false, keepForever: false, managedArtifacts: false, noUploadOnFailure: false, selectedRegion: 'us-east-1', showDirectlyInBrowser: false, sourceFile: '**/target/*.jar', storageClass: 'STANDARD', uploadFromSlave: false, useServerSideEncryption: false]], pluginFailureResultConstraint: 'FAILURE', profileName: 'test0-aws', userMetadata: []
                     
            }
}
```